# I'm trying to open an image in the terminal without any success

Tags: linux, command-line, find, pipe, xargs

I want to open an image from a specific date and time inside the terminal. I located the image with the following command:

```
# find . -type f -name '*2018-05-24*' | grep 18-46-31
./Screenshot from 2018-05-24 18-46-31.png
```

Now I want to open this image from the output above in the terminal but the command below doesn't seem to work.

```
# find . -type f -name '*2018-05-24*' | grep '18-46-31' | xargs xdg-open
```

What am I doing wrong? I used xargs(may be I'm using xargs wrong) to try to pass the output from grep as an option to xdg-open but I'm getting:

```
xdg-open: unexpected argument 'from'
Try 'xdg-open --help' for more information.
```

Comment: filename have spaces this is the issue.  try find . -type f -name '*2018-05-24*18-46-31*' -exec xdg-open {} \;

Comment: Good suggestion, will test it.

Answer (score 4):

`xargs`, by default, splits the input on *any* whitespace, so in the end, it runs `xdg-open` with the four arguments `./Screenshot`, `from`, `2018-05-24`, `18-46-31.png`. With GNU xargs you could use `xargs -d '\n'` to have it split on newlines instead, but you could do the whole thing with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*2018-05-24*18-46-31*' -exec xdg-open {} \;
```

(Strictly speaking, that's not the same as your `find`+`grep` combination, since the pattern forces the date and time to be in this order, and the time also has to be part of the filename itself. `find -name -name '*2018-05-24*' | grep 18-46-31` would also match `./18-46-31/2018-05-24.png`.)

Comment: thanks I will try your suggestion but I don't fully understand what your'e doing with the middle widlcard `*`, `-exec, {}` and the backslash.  Can you update your answer with an explanation of what these mean and what they do? Btw, isn't there a way that my command using pipe could be modified to make this work.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia See here for an explanation of `find -exec`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, the asterisks just mean "any number of any characters", so  `-name '*2018-05-24*18-46-31*'` matches filenames with `2018-05-24` and `18-46-31` and anything between, before and after them. You could swap a space in place of the middle `*`, if you know your filenames have just the space between the date and the time.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, exactly what I was looking for.